# List of global geopolitical areas?

Tags: data, administrative-boundaries, global

I'm building a fake-data maker in R (a package that will quickly generate realistic data for testing and training purposes). In order to be able to do geographical analysis stuff, **I'm looking for a table that has 3 columns: COUNTRY, REGION/DEPARTMENT, MUNICIPALITY. I would like to have this information for all the countries of the world** so that the user could develop a test for any region in the world. It doesn't matter if the information is imperfect, antiquated, different heterogeneous geographical units... none of that matters. I just need something fast fast fast that will provide a launching point.

If I had entity centroid lat/long it would be cool, but it's not necessary since part of the training is to learn how to geocode.

Where could this info be available or how could I hack this together?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a data and not a GIS question.

Comment: The best place to research open data sources is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for non-commercial purposes, you could use a the GADM dataset: http://gadm.org/version2

While it doesn't necessarily have the exact 3 columns you are looking for (because different areas of the world have different names for administrative divisions), GADM does have Admin0 (Country), Admin1 (State/Province), Admin2 (District) and up to Admin5 in some countries.

Hopefully this will suit your needs.

FYI - the Shapefile option is a .dbf which you can open with QGIS (http://qgis.org/en/site/) or ESRI Software.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I'll download the layers and try them out... it'll take some time to mark as accepted but I won't forget.